# How do I take a text file and turn it into a dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary, text-files

So what I am trying to do is load up all my usernames and passwords from a textfile into a dictionary to call upon them...

```
     def createacc():
                x = 0
                while x != 200:
                    print("\n")
                    x+=1
                answer = {}
                error = None
                with open('usernames.dat', 'r') as document:
                    for line in document:


                        n = line.replace("\n'","")

                        arts = n.replace("[","")

                        parts = arts.replace("['","")

                        nparts = parts.split("=")

                        line = parts


                        if not line:  # empty line?
                            continue
                        answer[line[0]] = line[1:]
                print("\n\n\n\n\n")
                print(answer)
                print("\n\n\n\n\n")


                if request.method == "POST":
                    if request.form['username'] == '' or request.form['password'] == "" or request.form['code'] != "30286":
                        error="Faliure to create account!! please try again"
                    else:
                        acc = open("usernames.dat","a+")

                        a = acc.readlines()
                        aaa = request.form['username'] +"="+ request.form['password'] + "\n"
                        acc.writelines(aaa)
                        acc.close()
                        return redirect(url_for('sms'))
                return render_template('newacc.html',error=error)
```

And What I was hoping my dictionary out would look like would be like so

`{'admin':'admin', 'PPGC': 'Default', 'DELTA': 'Readme'}`

and the result I am getting is

`{'a': 'dmin=admin\n', 'P': 'PGC\n', 'D': 'ELTA\n', 'N': 'AVI\n'}`

What do I need to do to get my desired dictionary?

Comment: What does your text file look like?

Comment: What should be inefficient here? Do you care about 10 CPU cycles more? Completely irrelevant comment...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your program writing the username, passwords in a textfile? If yes, I would suggest to use JSON or any other data interchange format. For example, with json you can do this

```
import json

user_dict = {'some user': 'some password'}

with open('my_database.json', 'w') as db:
    json.dump(user_dict, db)

# Now the data can be can easily loaded
user_data = json.load(open('my_database.json'))

# This will get you the dictionary back.
```

Comment: No what I am trying to do is write it to a file but when people are trying to login i need a dictionary there to so I am trying to make the dictionary into a textfile and then later on upload it into the program

Comment: Ok so what I wrote on top would still help. When you write a Dictionary to a text file instead of file write save it in JSON using the json.dump method. So whenever you need to read it all you need to do is load and you will get the Dictionary back.